# Setting up NAT for internet access on a connected router

Tags: 12.04, networking, router, wireless-access-point, nat

I'm setting up a NAT for a connected router to my laptop using the following command (IP forwarding is enabled):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.47.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

So basically I have a eth0 which is my laptop's LAN, and a USB-CAT5 -based connection from my laptop to a wireless router, which is eth1. And I am assigning a static IP to my eth1 interface (i.e. connected to the wireless router) using the following command:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.47.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

And I run ifconfig to make sure eth1 has this IP address:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:77:39:0e  
      inet addr:129.46.79.72  Bcast:129.46.79.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: 2002:c023:9c17:118:f5ea:ed5a:6c19:138d/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe77:390e/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2002:c023:9c17:118:2ad2:44ff:fe77:390e/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:289511 errors:0 dropped:324 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:103659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:87784569 (87.7 MB)  TX bytes:26739445 (26.7 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f0600000-f0620000 

eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:b6:0a:4c:5e  
      inet addr:192.168.47.1  Bcast:192.168.47.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:104328 (104.3 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The router's settings has been setup. My problem is that when I'm connected to the router, I don't have any internet connection. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to tell the machine that's acting as a router to forward the packages it receives and configure the default gateway, use this command:

```
sudo sysctl net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
```

To add a default gateway, also add:

```
sudo route add -net default gw X.X.X.X
```

Where X.X.X.X is the IP of your wireless router.

Comment: is it different than echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward , which enables IP_forwarding?!

Comment: It's the same order, but using sysctl. The result is the same, yes.

Comment: So, yeah...As I said, it is already enabled.

Comment: Try also enabling the gateway, see if that's the problem.

Comment: So xxx should be the static IP I've been trying to assign, right? 192.168.47.1

Comment: The IP that faces the internet, that is, the IP of the wireless router (I'm assuming that's the layout). Basically, you have to tell the machine that's acting as a bridge between the client and the computer where to send the packages that doesn't belong to the network behind the NAT, this is, Internet. This wouldn't be 192.168.47.1, but the IP of the router your computer is connectes.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if we are on the same page. So I've edited the question to ensure that. The internet goes to the Laptop through eth0, and goes to the router through eth1.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
sudo su

iptables -F

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.47.0/24 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t  nat  -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.47.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Well; no changes.
One thing which I'm not sure about is that when I click on the network icon near the clock, for eth1's wired network, it shows disconnected! However ifconfig shows it as UP !